Fit iframe (specifically height) to screen
When I dont specify anything, the iframe is tiny.
If i do width:100%; height:100%;, only the height is tiny
Im new to js, html, css and such so im not sure about some of this
.iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}


<iframe src="https://example.com" class="iframe" title="Testing"></iframe>
Im pretty sure even if i used 'width:1080px; height...' they wouldn't "fit" to the screen and resize to different browsers/devices.
Entire code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RPiCODE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      .iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://example.com" class="iframe" title="Testing"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>


In your code the iframe is sized relative to the body element. If you want to iframe to be full height you need to make the body full height as well. Alternatively you could use: width: 100vw; height: 100vh; for the iframe. These are absolute sizes, not relative sizes. See: CSS values and units

Percentage dimensions are relative to the element’s parent, except in the case of the root element (the <html> element) in which case they refer to the viewport. So it will work if you set height: 100% on the html element, the body element and the iframe element.


html, body, iframe {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #555;
  margin: 0;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
}
<iframe src="https://example.com" title="Testing"></iframe>



Alternatively you can use viewport units, vw and vh.


body {
  background: #555;
  margin: 0;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 0;
}
<iframe src="https://example.com" title="Testing"></iframe>



